# How to decide that a method must be synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

In this code taken from [this test thread code](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/source/ThreadTest2.java) a thread calls two methods `addToTotal()` and `countPrimes()` but only the former is marked synchronized.

What prevents interleaving when `countPrimes()` is being executed. Aren't the variables used by `countPrimes()` like i, min, max, count also shared resources. And what about `isPrime()` which is called by `countPrimes()` ?

```
   public class ThreadTest2 {

    private static final int START = 3000000;

    private static int total;

    synchronized private static void addToTotal(int x) {
        total = total + x;
        System.out.println(total + " primes found so far.");
    }

    private static class CountPrimesThread extends Thread {
        int count = 0;
        int min, max;
        public CountPrimesThread(int min, int max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }
        public void run() {
            count = countPrimes(min,max);
            System.out.println("There are " + count + 
                " primes between " + min + " and " + max);
            addToTotal(count);
        }
    }

    private static void countPrimesWithThreads(int numberOfThreads) {
        int increment = START/numberOfThreads;
        System.out.println("\nCounting primes between " + (START+1) + " and " 
            + (2*START) + " using " + numberOfThreads + " threads...\n");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CountPrimesThread[] worker = new CountPrimesThread[numberOfThreads];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
            worker[i] = new CountPrimesThread(START+i*increment+1, START+(i+1)*increment );
        total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
            worker[i].start();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
            while (worker[i].isAlive()) {
                try {
                    worker[i].join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println("\nThe number of primes is " + total + ".");
        System.out.println("\nTotal elapsed time:  " + (elapsedTime/1000.0) + " seconds.\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        if (processors == 1)
            System.out.println("Your computer has only 1 available processor.\n");
        else
            System.out.println("Your computer has " + processors + " available processors.\n");
        int numberOfThreads = 0;
        while (numberOfThreads < 1 || numberOfThreads > 5) {
            System.out.print("How many threads do you want to use  (from 1 to 5) ?  ");
            numberOfThreads = TextIO.getlnInt();
            if (numberOfThreads < 1 || numberOfThreads > 5)
                System.out.println("Please enter 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 !");
        }
        countPrimesWithThreads(numberOfThreads);
    }

    private static int countPrimes(int min, int max) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
            if (isPrime(i))
                count++;
        return count;
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int x) {
        int top = (int)Math.sqrt(x);
        for (int i = 2; i <= top; i++)
            if ( x % i == 0 )
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some good answers below.  Could comments about the code.  The `addToTotal()` method would be better if it was using an `AtomicLong`.    No additional method synchronization would be needed.  Also, _never_ catch an exception without at least logging it.  And any time you catch `InterruptedException` you should re-interrupt the thread with: `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What prevents interleaving when countPrimes() is being executed?

Nothing.  We don't need to prevent it (see below).  And since we don't need to, preventing interleaving would be a bad thing because it would reduce parallelism.

> Aren't the variables used by `countPrimes()` like `i`, `min`, `max,`count` also shared resources?

No.  They are local to the current thread; i.e. to the thread whose `run()` method call is in progress.  Nothing else shares them.

> And what about `isPrime()` which is called by `countPrimes()`?

Same deal.  It is only using local variables, so no synchronization is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

`countPrimes` does not need synchronization because it does not access any shared variable (it only works with the arguments and local variables). So there is nothing to synchronize.

On the other hand, the `total` variable is updated from several threads and the access needs to be synchronized to ensure correctness.

Comment: OK. I take this to mean that local variable and argument updates are automatically synchronized.

Comment: @Himanshu They are not synchronized, they are thread-local (only one thread can access them: the thread that is running the method).

Comment: @Himanshu - You don't *need* to synchronize something if it is only ever visible to one thread.  Local variables and only ever visible to one thread.

Answer (score 0):

The synchronized keyword simply acquires the monitor for some object. If another thread already has the monitor it will have to wait for that thread to finish before it can acquire it and proceed. Any piece of code that synchronizes on a common object will not be able to run concurrently since only one thread can acquire the monitor on that object at any given time. In the case of methods the monitor used is implicit. For non-static methods it's the instance it was called on, for static methods it's the Class for the type it's called on.

That's one possible reason but it hardly constitutes an accurate indication of when to use the keyword.

To answer the question I would say you use synchronized whenever you don't want two threads concurrently executing a critical section based upon a common monitor. The situations in which you would need this are many and riddled with far too many gotchas and exceptions to explain fully.

You can't prevent access to an entire class with synchronized. You can make every method synchronized, but still that's not quite the same thing. Plus, it only prevents other threads from accessing the critical section when synchronized on the same monitor.